# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.initializeApp')

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

Whenevr I open the debugger in safari I get an error saying that undefined is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.initializeApp') and it points toward firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);.

```
var firebase
let firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "removed",
    authDomain: "removed",
    projectId: "removed",
    storageBucket: "removed",
    messagingSenderId: "removed",
    appId: "removed"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let db = firebase.firestore();
```

Comment: `var firebase` initialises the `firebase` variable as `undefined`. I think perhaps you should start with the documentation ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I didn't put var firebase at the start but if I remove it another error pops up that says cant find variable firebase. If i put the var firebase at the top this error goes away and the undefined one comes back. I can't figure out the reason why its happening. –

Comment: I have followed the documentation I just put let firebase config instead of const firebase config

Comment: Ok so I changed everything to how it shows in the documentation and now instead of the cant find firebase var it now shows can’t find var intilize app

Comment: Start from the beginning... how did you [install Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize)? Are you using `npm` / `yarn` or are you using one of the [alternative methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup#from-the-cdn)

Comment: I didn't use npm /yarn. I used the cdn to install firebase.

Answer (score 1):

`firebase.initializeApp` is the v8 (and below) way of initializing the app. You could consider using the v9 (and above) style like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-app.js";
const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

[More details on initialization upgrades to v9 here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_initialization_code)

Or, using the Compat version (compatability with v8)

```
import firebase from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app-compat.js"

firebase.initializeApp({ /* config */ });
```